# Action Script 3 Redirect to url Variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect

I have made a flv file that plays a movie. Swf is loaded automatically before the site loads. When the movie ends i want to redirect back to a website url. Problem is that the website that I redirect back is not static.

But I know the url of the site from the url bar. Example:

The url is loaded here: http://myad.com

Current url adress: http://myad.com/reloader.html?ADURL=http://www.website.com/test.asp&

So I want at the last frame of the swf, to be redirected back to www.website.com

Any ideas what action script 3 code I need to use;

Thank you

edit: corrected adurl

Comment: your links are not working?
   
      href="#" // inside your url parameter reloads same page

Comment: links are example, not real ones

Comment: href="#" // inside your url parameter  get url"#"   been along time i have forgotton syntax